# Python 3 isinstance unexpected behavior when importing class from different file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-import, isinstance

I am trying to import a class from one file and check if is an instance of that  class in the file that it was defined in. The problem is that instead of returning `True` from the`isinstance()` function, it returns `False`, because it was initialised in a different file.

Here is a working example.

Say you have `file1.py`:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

def main(class_obj):
    # Prints false and is type <class 'file1.Foo'>
    print(type(class_obj))
    print(isinstance(class_obj, Foo))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from file2 import get_class
    main(get_class())
```

And `file2.py`:

```py
from file1 import Foo

def get_class():
    foo = Foo("argument")
    return foo
```

It prints `False` and the type is `<class 'file1.Foo'>`. What I found interesting is that if you initialize the `Foo` class in `file1` where is was defined, it returns `True`.

```py
# Add to main() function in file1
# Returns true and is type <class '__main__.Foo'>
foo_local = Foo("argument")  # Class initiated in __main__ seems to work
print(type(foo_local))
print(isinstance(foo_local, Foo))
```

I found that if you initiate a class outside of the file where it is defined, it is a different "class" than if you initiate the class inside the file where it was defined.

```py
# Different Classes?
<class 'file1.Foo'>  # From other file (`file2.py`)
<class '__main__.Foo'>  # From same file (`file1.py`)
```

---

So my question is:

How can I work around this so that even the classes initiated outside of the `file1` can return `True` on the `isinstance()` function? To reword it, how can I make it so that the `Foo` class is the "same" in `file1.py` and `file2.py`? I Python 3.6.7 if it matters.

Comment: always use the [python] generic tag when asking a python related question. Use version-specific tags at your discretion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starkly simple answer is to **never use** `if __name__=="__main__"`.  It’s a clever trick, to be sure, but it doesn’t do what anyone thinks it does.  It’s supposed to make a file be a module **and** a script, but (because the processes for finding and running modules and scripts are so different) what it actually does is let the file be a module **or** a script, **separately**.  The trick contains a hint as to this shortcoming: `__name__` in a module is supposed to be its key in `sys.modules`, and if it’s “__main__” that’s not any normal module at all.  (It is in fact possible to `import __main__` and get a module object whose attributes are the global variables in the script!)

In your case, where `file1.py` gets used once as a script and then, via the module `file2`, as a module, it is actually loaded **twice**.  Each load creates an unrelated (if similar) class `Foo`; it doesn’t matter **where** each class is used, just which one.  (`file1` could even import *itself* and would get the “module version”.)  Note that the classes need not be “the same”; the very same `if` trick could be used to give them different members or base classes, or could even control which `class Foo` statement is executed.

If you want to use `python -m`, which is a perfectly reasonable desire for installation reasons, the **least broken** way of using it is via a `__main__.py` in a package otherwise used via `import`.  It’s *still* possible to import it, which probably doesn’t do anything good, but no one (aside from naïve code that recursively imports every module in a package) will do so.

Comment: I wouldn't say to never use `if __name__ == '__main__'`, especially because cases like the `multiprocessing` module exist, where omitting the guard can completely break your program. That said, Python's whole `__main__` thing is pretty badly designed, and this particular interaction with circular imports is one of the weirder, more painful parts.

Comment: @user2357112: Perhaps I should say not to use it *in a module* (despite that being its original purpose).  `multiprocessing` needing it (when not using fork) just means that separating out a module from a (then) trivial driver script is an even better idea than usual.